# Get a list of forms that doesn't inherit another form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a base form (`BaseForm`) which needs to be inherited from all the forms in the project. Some of them inherit it, others not. How can I get a list of all those forms who currently don't inherit it because we have a lot of forms and will be time consuming to go and check if each one of them inherits this form? Maybe some reflection ?

Comment: can't you just do a solution wide search for the text `: BaseFormName`?

Comment: this will give me all the forms that inherit it. I guess it's faster to get the list of the forms that DOESN't inherit it

Comment: Then search for `: Form`

Comment: yes, or use a regexp if you want to get clever (to deal with multiple inheritance etc), something like `:.*^BaseFormName`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the check [Type.IsSubclassOf()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.issubclassof.aspx).

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
Type baseType = typeof(BaseForm);

foreach (Type type in assembly.GetTypes().Where(t => (t.FullName.Contains("Form") && (t != baseType))))
{
    if (type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(BaseForm)))
        Console.WriteLine("{0} is subclass of {1}", type, baseType);
}
```

Comment: Specifically something like: `var list = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().Where(t => t.IsSubclassOf(typeof(BaseFormName)));`

Comment: Great, I guess that'l do it. You can post it as answer

Answer (score 3):

```
Type formType = typeof(Form);

foreach (Type type in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes())
   if (formType.IsAssignableFrom(type))
   {
      // print the list of forms
   }
```